# Browser address will not be displayed correctly in ui-route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the following example :

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

Default Page URL  in the example above :

```
 http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/
```

But for me it is like this:

```
 http://localhost:25768/Admin#/
```

why ?

Should be like this:

```
 http://localhost:25768/Admin/#/
```

note : Admin is Controller in MVC.

my codes :

app.js :

```
angular.module('uiRouterApp', [
        'uiRouterApp.home',
        'ui.router',
        'ngAnimate'
    ])
    .run(
        [
            '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
            function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
                $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
            }
        ]
    )
    .config(
        [
            '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $urlRouterProvider
                    .when('/c?id', '/contacts/:id')
                    .when('/user/:id', '/contacts/:id')
                    .otherwise('/');
            }
        ]
    );
```

home.js :

```
angular.module('uiRouterApp.home', [
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(
        [
            '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/',
                        templateUrl: 'Scripts/ui-route/home/home.html',
                    });
            }
        ]
    );
```

layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="uiRouterApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <title ng-bind="$state.current.name + ' - ui-router'">@ViewBag.Title</title>

</head>
<body class="container adminBackground">
    <div class="min1170px">
        <div class="adminHeader">
            <img class="adminLeftLogoHeader" src="/Images/juventusLogo.png" />
            <img class="adminRightLogoHeader" src="/Images/apkAndroid.png" />
            <div class="adminTitleHeader">

            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">Main</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbarMenuHeader">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#"> @User.Identity.Name</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section>
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularJs")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Index page in Admin Controller :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manager";
    Layout = "../Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

**Update :**

when url is : `http://localhost:25768/Admin`

[image]

and url change to :

```
http://localhost:25768/Admin#/
```

no error and it works. but url is `http://localhost:25768/Admin#/`    !!!! not good

when url is : `localhost:25768/Admin/`

[image]

so url change to :

```
http://localhost:25768/Admin/#/
```

error in angular :

```
GET http://localhost:25768/Admin/Scripts/ui-route/home/home.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm  change the templateUrl to

```
 templateUrl: '/Scripts/ui-route/home/home.html',
```

Then, I changed the code as follows:

```
      public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var path = Request.Path;

            if (path == "/Admin")
            {
                return Redirect("/Admin/");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

**It works.**

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the ASP.NET MVC side... we have to be sure, that

- browser will be using the trailing slash
- or redirect it, if not...

This should be the content of your Index action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var root = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
    var applicationPath = Request.ApplicationPath;
    var path = Request.Path;

    var hasTraillingSlash = 
          root.Equals(applicationPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
       || !applicationPath.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    if (!hasTraillingSlash)
    {
        return Redirect(root + "#");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Check this Q & A:

- [Workaround for MVC misbehaviour with missing trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486416/)

Comment: I've been using your code. But it did not work. when url= 'http://localhost:25768/Admin#/' => root ="/" and applicationPath ="/" and path ="/Admin". so hasTraillingSlash = true.

Comment: Well, the url is  `localhost:25768/Admin` or  `localhost:25768/Admin/` no hash at the end... browser never sends the part after the hash to the server. So your url with or without trailing slash is what will reach the server... This code is working for me (us) ... other words: I am saying, that if you apply my snippet properly, it will correctly redirect to /Admin/ ... always

Comment: So, the issue was of a different kind... all the time I was *wrongly* expecting that the `Admin` is virtual applicaiton... **not** a controller. If that would be this way, all the above would be enough. But because Admin is Controller, it brings another deepth in the url.. not needed one. You should for sure use the `localhost:25768/` for your index action. I.e. it should be Home Controller and its action Index... or just change the url routing setting (that default is Admin not Home)... These two thinkg (relative path and url routing for MVC) cannot work together...

Comment: This answer worked for me. It was working on localhost fine, but when pushed to our server, it stopped working. Working fine now with this answer. Thanks so much!!