# error when refreshing page angularjs ui router

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs and i'm making a website using ASP.NET MVC and AngularJs.I used angularjs ui router for route from one page to another.

With ui-sref tag every thing is ok but when user refreshes the browser page or enter url it fails to match to a state.

The question is how to set states and what actions needed in my controllers.
here are my codes.if any other code is required tell me.


my controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NewsListPage()
    {
        return Redirect("#NewsListPage");
    }

    public ActionResult NewsDetailPage(int? newsId)
    {
        return Redirect("#NewsDetailPage");
    }
```

my main angular file including module creation and config

```
var app = angular.module('abtinApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('A',
        {
            url: '/News/NewsListPage',
            templateUrl: '/Angular/NewsListPage'
        })
        .state('B',
        {
            url: '/News/NewsDetailPage/:newsId',
            templateUrl: '/Angular/NewsDetailPage'
        })
        .state('C',
        {
            url: '^/News/NewsDetailPage/:newsId',
            templateUrl: '/Angular/NewsDetailPage'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/News/NewsListPage');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });

}
]);
```

my index.cshtml

```
...
<div ng-app="abtinApp">
            <a ui-sref=".A">Main</a>
            <a ui-sref=".B">Detail</a>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
...
```

angular controller

```
    public ActionResult NewsDetailPage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NewsListPage()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and NewsDetailPage.cshtml

```
<div ng-controller="NewsDetailController">
    <h3>Details</h3>

    <h3>{{newsId}}</h3>
</div>
```

and NewsListPage.cshtml

```
<h3>News</h3>
<div ng-controller="NewsController">
<div ng-repeat="newsItem in newsToShow">
<h3>
    <a ui-sref="B({newsId: '{{newsItem.Id}}'})">   {{newsItem.Title}}</a>
</h3>
<p>
    {{newsItem.NewsSummary}}
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

there is nothing especial in my angular controllers.
thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode. Specifically, either the IIS rewrites in web.config, or the C# rewrites in Global.asax.

Comment: also, you should be aware of the complications of using `requireBase: false`; Without a `<base>` tag, the initial URL will need to match exactly in every instance, making relative URLs relative to the *server* instead of relative to other pages within the app.

Comment: @Claies : you mean i copy the c# code in my golbal.asax?

Comment: do you have an understanding of how html5Mode works?  The code in the ui-router FAQ is a sample of possible ways to configure your server, but you should have some understanding of what the code is trying to accomplish....

Comment: @Claies i don't understand what to do with that link,could you explain?

Comment: there are at least a dozen articles on this site that describe html5Mode and when to use it, how to use it, how to configure your server, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html5Mode+MVC

Comment: @ Claies i have read some of the postes from the above link.almost all of them say that move all request to first angular page but i can't because the angular app is just for one of my pages the rest are should be simple asp.net mvc

Comment: @Claies look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169968/angularjs-ui-router-stateprovider-cant-read-my-abstract-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot and wasting some time,i found out by removing

**$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });**

every thing is fine but the new problem will be the ugly urls that is not important to me.

still any other answer will be appreciated.