# angularjs with cshtml page only not html pages with web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having asp. net mvc4 project. Angularjs is integrated. 
I have  already built HTML pages and WEB APIs 2 as per previous requirements.

Now for some reason i have to go with CSHTML pages. previously I had only web api project template so i couldnt go with cshtml pages as ONLY MVC controller can return partial page(cshtml) but i was using only web apis...

So changed whole project template and so now i can have mvc controllers... ...

In short,  currently I have mvc4 project with already built web apis and html pages.....

I just want to use CSHTML pages instead of using HTML pages rest things should be as they are...

Is it possible?

I may sound silly but it is need right now. help would be greatly appreciated...

Web apis,  cshtml pages and angularjs only. not web apis,  html pages and angularjs.

If I replace `html` pages by `cshtml,`  how would angular route get affected?

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is how I use it.

There is **`index.cshtml`** like this

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@{ Layout = null; }<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="MyProject">
<head>
    <title data-ng-controller="TitleCtrl" data-ng-bind="Title">My Project</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/min/css")
</head>
<body class="body" id="body">

    <div class="body" data-ui-view="body"></div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/js/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/MyProject")
</body>
</html>
```

*NOTE: using angular `UI-Router`, that's why `ui-view` is in palce*

But still there must be **`HomeController`**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // below I do some tricks to make app running on 
        // http://mydomain/app as well as on
        // http://mydomain/app/  (see the / at the end)

        var root = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
        var applicationPath = Request.ApplicationPath;
        var path = Request.Path;
        var hasTraillingSlash = root.Equals(applicationPath
                                      , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || !applicationPath.Equals(path
                                      , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (!hasTraillingSlash)
        {
            return Redirect(root + "#");
        }

        // my view is not in Views, but in the root of a web project
        return View("~/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

So, this way I can use power of Bundle configureation (javascript, css) ... while starting angular at `http://mydomain/app` or `http://mydomain/app/`. *Check also similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24988979/1679310)*

Also in global.asax, we should configura ASP.NET MVC:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("fonts*.woff");

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

while web API should be:

```
const string IdPattern = @"\d+|[A-Za-z]{1,2}";
public static void SetRouting(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // some custom routes
    ...            

    // and a default one
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
        , constraints: new { id = IdPattern }
        , defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: lets say I have menu which has products page.  after reaching to dashboard if i click products menu list,  how would it redirect me to products.cshtml page?

Comment: right now i have set ui router like this...  url:'/products',  template:'/products. html'

Comment: I extended my answer with Routing for MVC (the Home/Index) and Web API. The trick is, that while the Home / Index is loaded and the index.csthml is rendered... we do not need any redirectons. We will hav SPA... now it is Angular job to load all the views ...

Comment: I see... If you want to serve also the "Views" as .csthml you need controllers and actions for them. But I have to confirm, that after using it for most then 2 years... only INDEX.csthml is enough. The rest could be some templates in .html. Just html

Comment: Once again. You cannot add `.csthml` page!!! Clear? You **CANNOT** add `.csthml`. You can target `Controller` and `Action`... which renders `.csthml`. Is it clear now? so `products.csthml` either must be reached as `mydomain/products/list` and there must be `ProductController` with action `List()` and that will render the `products.cshtml`. **Is that clear now?** BUT what I am trying to say is: use only .csthml and homecontroller ... for your SPA page (index.cshtml). The rest could really be just .html. No need to serve that as MVC controller/action/view... do you understand me? does it help?

Comment: true.  agreed.  previously i had only one index.cshtml pages i was using it to inject other html views...  but now it is a need to have all cshtml pages rather than having html pages....  so i wonder how would i do?

Comment: As I said. You can do it, BUT only if there will be controller and action for each such .cshtml. Why? because runtime won't serve .cshtml to client. No way. It wll be used as a renderer for Action result. So my suggestion: DO NOT convert html to csthml for you views. no need for that. NO advantage no benefit...

Comment: so after hard work i could do something like this....  productsController. cs->index will return products. cshtml page.... n rest things as they are.  this way problem is if i have 20 pages,  i have to add 20 mvc controller(as per my knowlege)  which seems bad approach to me.....

Comment: YES YES. Exactly. You've got the point. SO, do not do it. Just use the index.cshtml as I showed above for start of your Angular app... I am using it for more then 2 years... and have to say... it is really ok just use .html for all the views. it will work. you will see. but there is a big benefit of having the index.html served as Home/Index and .csthml ... becuase of BundleConfig...

Comment: agreed even i used to have one index.cshtml n other html pages only.. no prbm with it.  but is just said to be done so looking for some work around nothing else.... even i know it is not good approach.....

Comment: Wish that my answer and comments helped somehow. Enjoy all these amazing features, angular, web api, bundle .. ;) good luck

Comment: @RadimKöhler you should write a blog post on this. btw which all nugets do I need to use if I just need bundling and minification as you mentioned above??

Comment: @HarishR thanks for a nice comment! thanks. As you most likely know I use more packages through the nuget *(for example NHibernate ... ;)* so, not fully sure which are really needed just for minification... But I guess that we need all for MVC (to make *.cshtml* running there must be controller and action) `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor`. Maybe even `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` and `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure`. Then for **Bundling** `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` and it should require `WebGrease`. It could seem to be a lot but ... we gain: **`.Include("myscripts/*.js`**

Comment: exactly, i really never wanted to use asp.net MVC with angular, but it seems just to get the bundling/minification I will have to go with MVC, sadly