# Unable to access ExpressJS route via href link

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not sure if this is a security feature or if I'm missing something obvious.  I need to access one of my ExpressJS routes directly via a standard link on the page.

If I type the URL in to my browser location bar, I get the desired result.  However, if I put that exact URL in a standard link on one of the pages on the site, the route never gets hit.

EDIT: Even if I pull this out of the router and add directly to app.js I get the same results.  I'm simply trying to use Passport's Facebook authentication.  The first route looks like this:

```
router.get('/login/facebook', function(req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate('facebook')(req, res, next);
});
```

I realize the req function wrapper is not needed, I was using it for debugging so I could see when the route gets called.

If I set a breakpoint there, it works fine if I just type the "/api/login/facebook" URL into my browser,  but if I put the exact URL in a link on the page, the route never gets hit.

Comment: ideally what you said should work. no more complexity.

Comment: Show the code of the router, pls

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was caused by Angular's routing mechanism intercepting the links.  I found the solution here:

[How to get Angular UI Router to respect "non-routed" URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127661/how-to-get-angular-ui-router-to-respect-non-routed-urls)