# Angular UI-Route w/ Custom Segments

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to use angular's ui-router (in HTML5 mode) with an IIS/MVC website to support custom segments in the URL. For example:

http://www.example.com/{client}/{location}/dashboard

Update: Doing so more digging it looks like I might be able to accomplish this by setting <base href="/{client}/{location}/" /> Is there a better alternative to this?

Comment: If you want to check how to set the server, asp.net mvc - http://stackoverflow.com/q/27706712/1679310 could give you some hints...

Comment: I don't see an actual question