# How to minimize all custom java script files used in an AngularJs project?

Tags: angularjs, tfs, msbuild, gruntjs

It is possible to minimize all custom java script file Manually or Automatically ?

We are using TFS for source code management , Its also possible that auto minimize Java script file by source control system or build system , when deploy code in windows Azure system or web deploy?

Note - I am not using .net application its core AngularJs application and communication done by web-api hosted on other server.

Comment: There are links how it could be done using some features of .net world http://stackoverflow.com/a/27675441/1679310 and with html5 mode http://stackoverflow.com/a/27707238/1679310

Comment: Application not using any .net features, Its SPA application and used web api from other source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, you could integrate a build script runner like Grunt with your TFS that could minify all your javascript files. When you use Grunt you can also run it manually when developing.

I would suggest you take some time to get familiar with build script runners like Grunt to see what the possibilities are.

Comment: Grunt process can run on TFS before auto deployment ?

Comment: [grunt with tfs auto deployment](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/06/30/use-grunt-manage-javascript-builds-tfs/) and [Grunt web deployment tasks](http://joeriks.com/2013/08/06/can-i-benefit-from-grunt-for-my-visual-studio-based-web-development/)

Comment: Thanks, If my question make sense , then make it useful +