# How to trigger router's state on page load?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

In my app I have this server-generated link:
http://localhost:3000/people#/users

When I click on it I get redirected to the following HTML page with Angular `UI-Router` script:

```
<a ui-sref="users">Users</a>      
<a ui-sref="invitations">Invitations</a>       
<div ui-view></div>
```

The problem is - `users` state does not get triggered automatically on page load. I need to manually click on it and only then the corresponding `UI-Router` state gets triggered.

Here's my config file:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('users', {
      url: "/users",
      templateUrl: "assets/partials/users.html"
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sgPZKbCrL11ZSUKHtrgD?p=preview)

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/users');

  // States
  $stateProvider
    .state('users', {
      url: "/users",
      templateUrl: "assets/partials/users.html"
    });
```

The **`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/users');`** will redirect to defined page when none is provided

This links in index.html will work as well

```
  href
  <a href="#/users">
  ui-sref      
  <a ui-sref="users">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sgPZKbCrL11ZSUKHtrgD?p=preview)

If that should be more dynamic, please check the:

#### [Angular - Dynamically Choose Starting State](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30477922/1679310)

In case, that our issue is that application is working with this init page:

```
http://domain/app/
```

but not without the trailing slash

```
http://domain/app
```

We have to do some redirection on a server. (Redirection is needed to make all the relative path properly working) there are some how to with asp.net mvc

#### [Browser address will not be displayed correctly in ui-route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24987100/1679310)

Comment: It works in your fiddle, but not in my code... I have added a controller to a state 'users' with debug message: console.log('yo') and it does not get displayed in console when loading this page in browser. I try to break your plunker, thanks :)

Comment: Ok, do you have more info? I'd suggest, try to "break my plunker" and I could assist, if you want...

Comment: Here's your "breaked" plunker:  http://run.plnkr.co/nCVUSkQgKoF5iGHC#/users     State won't get triggered until you add backslash to a URL like so: http://run.plnkr.co/nCVUSkQgKoF5iGHC/#/users   Is adding this backslash is mandatory thing?

Comment: Here's preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/rRI7WQxwWmAYZh9iL3Ea?p=preview   In Preview your code works because you change states after page already loaded. Try to launch a preview in a separate window, then change URL to delete backslash at the end( as in my  examples earlier) and you will see it does not work...

Comment: I see now, what is your real issue. It is proper **server** configuration what is your problem. Maybe check this https://gist.github.com/frankgeerlings/1711560 for an example with .NET MVC. In a nutshell - you have to force (on a server) the browser to redirect to the app with slash. It is a must. That's how plunker (your app) is working (almost any web server with virtual applications. Without some server redirection (without slash to with slash) the angular application does not have correct access to relative path (it searches for xxxxxxxscript.js while it needs xxxxx/script.js) makes sense?